# Create 'Add to Home Screen' shortcut for local offline HTML page

Tags: chrome-for-android, home-screen-shortcuts

I have developed a web-based HTML and Javascript app which is distributed to company mobile phones via email or USB transfer as a zip file, which I would like to set up on people's devices with a shortcut on their home screen.

However, I can't get the option in the Chrome browser to add it as a shortcut for the offline page.

The option only becomes available if, for example, I upload the package to my online webspace and then load that URL in chrome. This isn't an option, as the app will load in confidential information which I don't want online.

Are there any solutions or alternative options for this?

Comment: On the destination devices, do you have Root Access or not ?

Answer (score 2):

## 1. Using Chrome Browser (without root)

If you are looking for a solution using Chrome app, `Chrome isn't associated with Html files`, thus you can't associate it with HTML files, but you can:

> **P.S**: Allow the storage permission for the Chrome App

- Open Chrome Browser
- Type the path of your file Ex: `file://mnt/sdcard/Documents/App/index.html`
- Goto Options Menu (Three dots on the upper right)
- Tick the Star on the top to Bookmark the html file in Mobile Bookmarks.
- From your launcher put the "Chrome Bookmarks" widget on the desktop to access your bookmarked local file.

## 2. Using Total Commander (without root)

> **P.S**: First, Allow the storage permission for the Total Commander App

- Install & Launch [Total Commander - file manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander&hl=en)
- Locate your "index.html" file.
- Tap & maintain on the  index.html file.
- From the pop-up Menu, tick the option "Create Link on Desktop"
- Select the shortcut name.
- Select the app used to open HTML files (I suggest to install Opera or Firefox before this)
- Choose an Icon if you want.
- Tap OK/ Apply.

## 3. Using Opera Browser (without root)

Opera Browser is a solution for your situation, maybe other browsers are also fine.

> **P.S**: First, Allow the storage permission for the Opera App

- Install [Opera browser - news & search](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opera.browser&hl=en)
- Type the path of your file Ex: `file://mnt/sdcard/Documents/App/index.html`
- Goto Options Menu (Three dots on the upper right)
- At the bottom of the Option Menu, tick the option "Home Screen"
- Select the shortcut name, and tap Add.

Comment: chrome does not show the "add to home page" menu item on local files; same happens with embedded Samsung Internet Explorer on my Samsung S7.

Adding the "chrome bookmarks widget" results in adding links for ALL bookmarks, not just one.

Answer (score 1):

Download the page, open it in chrome, click the three dots in the top right and select 'Add to home'

Edit: Just realized, I'm using the Brave browser (free on google play) and it works. It looks a lot like Chrome so it doesn't take long to get used to it.

Edit #2: Orfox browser (Tor browser), also free, is able to do it. Just open the file and create a shortcut, just like with normal pages in chrome. This is a tor browser though, but maybe there are other browser that are lighter and also able to do it. Firefox browser also does the trick. Click the 3 dots in the top right, press page and create shortcut.

Comment: Nope, didn't work even with the Brave browser. 'Add to home' doesn't even appear if the file path is like `file:///sdcard/Documents/App/index.html`. Possibly due to the fact that a local file isn't served over https? In which case, is there an alternative...?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative I am using to access a local HTML via (my Samsung) Home Screen.

1. Have a shortcut to Samsung Internet (because it allows Locked Tab)
2. Open the HTML file manually (eg. Using My Files file manager, "Open With" Samsung Internet)
3. Tap on the Tabs button to display the list of open tabs, press and hold the 'RecyclerView' of the tab showing the HTML file, choose to Lock it.

Answer (score 0):

I use a simple app called  Website Shortcut created by Deltac Development. This app may work for your needs and can be edited and customized (i.e. company logo, changing path to different location, etc)